# Performing massive insert

Tags: java, oracle, maven

a little time ago I concluded my class diagram and now I want to populate it in a massive way. I made my database (Oracle 10g) from  java objects through the ddl-generation function of EclipseLink. Now my doubt is how to make this bulk insert.

I thought to do this in two way:

- Since I think to use also spring and maven during the development, I
  thought to read the data from an file and to persist them during test
  life cycle.
- Or serching on google I saw a few example like [Bulk insert with oracle](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bulk_insert.html)

Any suggestion about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JDBC for multiple insert by using batch insert like below.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

//...

Connection connection = new getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

for (Employee employee: employees) {
    String query = "insert into employee (name, city) values('"
            + employee.getName() + "','" + employee.getCity + "')";
    statement.addBatch(query);
}
statement.executeBatch();
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Spring consider JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate

Comment: Thanks, I think to use it to popular my db. Do you know a good tool to test the performarce of my db after the bulk insert?

Comment: in this case simple System.currentTimeMillis - t0 should be ok